# How do mongoengine filter field not null?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongoengine

I want to filter data with `category` value, but I don't know how to do this in `mongoengine`.

I try:

```
data = Data.objects.exclude(category="").order_by('-datetime')[:500]
```

But got error:

```
exclude() got an unexpected keyword argument 'category'
```

I didn't find the method in document, how do you do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the feeling you're mixing up two concepts : filtering documents, and returning document subsets.

#### Returning a document subset

`exclude` tells mongo to return selected documents without the category field. It won't filter the documents, just return the same documents, but without the category field: document subsets. Stripping out what you don't need improves performance. `exclude` and `only` achieve the same goal, except `exclude` blacklists fields, while `only` whitelists fields.

#### Filtering documents

What you want is to filter documents using a Queryset:

```
data = Data.objects({'category':{'$ne':''}}).order_by('-datetime')[:500]
```

or using the [double underscore syntax](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html?highlight=underscore#query-operators):

```
data = Data.objects(category__ne='').order_by('-datetime')[:500]
```

See [the tutorial](http://docs.mongoengine.org/tutorial.html#searching-our-posts-by-tag).

Comment: `limit` and slice are the same here is the [doc](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html?highlight=limit#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.limit)

Answer (score 1):

The [`.exclude()`](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.exclude) method takes only positional arguments; fields name. That being you need to use a [query operator](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html#query-operators) to filter out document where category is empty string using `category__ne=''`

```
data = Data.objects(category__ne='').order_by('-datetime')[:500]
```